# How to open modal in bootstrap without triggering any button or link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, servlets

We are verifying email Id with the help of servlet and on verifying ,a bootstrap modal should open asking user to answer security question.
But that modal with security question is opening only on clicking a button or link.
How to do it without using any button or link?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the docs? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Comment: I have read the docs but I don't understand how to do it without jquery

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api

Comment: Or just look at the css of opened modals, so you can render the html with modal already opened (it's just `fade`/`in` classes and `display:none`/`display:block`

Comment: we have tried display:block ,Its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... On verifying, use the id of the Modal container to display it as such

```
$("#MyModal").modal('show');
```

That should do the trick

If the current page would only load if the email has been verified then you can try this

```
<script>
// This would automatically run when page loads.

$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#MyModal").modal('show');

});
</script>
```

Comment: I am new to bootstrap and jquery.Can you please tell me where to write this method

Comment: @Amit how are you currently verifying the email? Are you returning anything to the page to indicate that it was successful?

Comment: yes if the email is verified then it will automatically set it's secret question in another modal but this modal comes only after clicking a link .

Comment: @Amit check my edited answer

Comment: actually our flow is like this:First our email is verified by the server and if it is correct then a new modal should open asking for secret question-answer.But rright now we are doing this by clicking on a link,modal is opening

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">SecretQuestion</button> this code we are using to open modak from our jsp page But we don't want any link instead directly the modak should open from jsp page

Comment: @Amit seems you are checking it on the same page...  After verification by the server... I believe you are checking for something instead of showing the link to the Modal... So instead of showing the link or doing any similar stuff, you can create a new Javascript function and put the Modal code in it function loadModal()  { $("#MyModal").modal('show');}

Comment: actually after checking it opens a new modal...so how to put the link under any javascript function

Comment: JSP is receiving data from servlet and to show that data on modal we have put a button.We want that modal to open automatically after receiving data from servlet

Comment: @Amit can you edit your question above to show how you are receiving the data from the servlet

Comment: Through servlet we are receiving secret question using request.get attribute

Comment: Thanks .Your code really helped

Comment: @Amit Glad i could help... Dont forget to vote up or mark it as answer :)